# Why do we not have any subgroup of ${\mathbb Z}/{4 \mathbb Z}$ which maps isomorphically to the quotient group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

I have recently started watching the video lectures of the Harvard University Extension School regarding abstract algebra taught by Benedict Gross. I am now in lecture 9 where various results of vector spaces are being taught. At the end of the lecture the instructor has introduced the concept of quotient vector space. He showed that for a subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$ there is a subspace of the vector space say $W'$ such that $W'$ maps isomorphically to $V/W$. But he cautioned with a Bourbaki sign that this result is not necessarily valid for groups. For instance he took $G={\mathbb Z} / {4 \mathbb Z}$ and $H = {2 \mathbb Z} /{4 \mathbb Z}$. Then clearly $${\mathbb Z } /{2 \mathbb Z} \simeq {2 \mathbb Z}/{4 \mathbb Z} \subset {\mathbb Z}/{4 \mathbb Z}.$$ But he claimed that there does not exist any subgroup $H'$ of $G$ which maps isomorphically to $G/H$. I don't understand this part of this lecture. Why is it so happening?

Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It seems strange to ask why something does not happen!

Comment: This is much easier to understand in the language of exact sequences.  The teacher is just saying that short exact sequences of groups (even abelian groups...i.e., $\Bbb{Z}$-modules) don't always split, but short exact sequences of vector spaces (i.e., $K$-modules for a field $K$) do.

Comment: Indeed, @DerekHolt, I counsel never to ask why something is not true, because *In mathematics, nothing is true*, unless there’s a proof showing that it’s true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, G/H is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ so if H′ maps isomorphically to the quotient, then there needs to be an element of order 2 not in the kernel. But there is only one element of order 2 and it is in the kernel.

Comment: If we consider the subgroup $H'=\left < \bar 2 \right >$ in ${\mathbb Z}/ {4 \mathbb Z}$. Then $H' \simeq G/H$. Is it not so?

Comment: As any group of prime order $p$ is cyclic  and hence it is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z} / {p \mathbb Z}$. Here $p=2$.

Comment: Yes, $H' \cong G/H$ but under the quotient map, $H'$ maps to $0$. Gross is saying that there is subgroup $H'$ that is isomorphic to the quotient under the quotient map. You aren't allowed to choose an arbitrary map as your isomorphism.

Comment: That said, there are also groups $G$ where there is no subgroup $H'$ that is isomorphic to the quotient under any map. That is, the quotient is not a subgroup of $G$. An example is $Q_8$, the quaternionic group where you take $H$ to be the center $\mathbb Z/2$ and the then the quotient is the Klein 4 group which is not a subgroup of $Q_8$.

Comment: Oh! I see. But I don't understand why the quotient is not a subgroup of $G$? It may be thought of as a subgroup of the original group in the notion of isomorphism. As in this case the quotient is ${\Bbb Z/ 2 \Bbb Z} \simeq {2 \Bbb Z} / {4 \Bbb Z} \subset {\Bbb Z} / { 4 \Bbb Z}$.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking exactly. Something that might help: Two groups can be isomorphic through different isomorphisms. What is asserted here is that the given quotient map does not induce an isomorphism on any subgroup. As you say, there is a different isomorphism between the quotient and the subgroup in this specific case.

Comment: Note that I did give a different example where there is no such isomorphism between the quotient and the subgroup. In general, get into the habit of saying isomorphism by this specific map instead of just isomorphic. This will help you remember that isomorphisms are always through specific maps and this map is often important to do anything concrete.

Answer (score 0):

What he is saying amounts to saying that any surjective homomorphism of vector spaces $f:V\rightarrow W$ has a "right-inverse" homomorphism $g:W\rightarrow V$ such that $fg:W\rightarrow W$ is the identity on $W$ but that when $f$ is instead of surjective homomorphism of groups, there may be no such $g$.  When there is such a $g$, we call it a "section" of $f$ and say that $f$ "splits".